# XPath following-sibling with multiple conditions

Tags: xpath

I have the following xml document. I am trying to select any child which has a sibling with the same value2 and where value3 is not Closed.

```
<root>
  <child>
    <value1>Type A</value1>
    <value2>Class 1</value2>
    <value3>Active</value3>
  </child>
  <child>
    <value1>Type B</value1>
    <value2>Class 1</value2>
    <value3>Closed</value3>
  </child>
  <child>
    <value1>Type C</value1>
    <value2>Class 2</value2>
    <value3>Active</value3>
  </child>
  <child>
    <value1>Type D</value1>
    <value2>Class 2</value2>
    <value3>Active</value3>
  </child>
  <child>
    <value1>Type E</value1>
    <value2>Class 3</value2>
    <value3>Active</value3>
  </child>
</root>
```

My attempt is:

> //child[following-sibling::child/value2=value2 and value3!='Closed']

but this is not having the desired result of applying the multiple conditions to the following-sibling function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it return all the following siblings where `value3 != closed`?

Comment: No it returns Type A and Type C which do have another child with the matching value2, but the second child of Type A is Closed and therefore should not be returned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//child[value2 = following-sibling::child[not(value3 = 'Closed')]/value2]
```

To apply to any sibling, union the `following-sibling` and the `preceding-sibling` axes.

```
//child[value2 = (following-sibling::child | preceding-sibling::child)[not(value3 = 'Closed')]/value2]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed...just added a "and value3!='Closed'" to ensure that the first child was not cancelled either.